# Closest number in string to specific phrase

Tags: php, regex, string

I've got such a string:

```
$string = "Serving Time: 5mins
Cooking time 10 mins
Servings 4
Author: Somebody

Directions

1...
2..."
```

I want to get output of Cooking time, it means closest digit to phrase: "Cooking time" and also I want to get closes digit to phrase "Servings"

So output would be

```
$serves = some_kind_of_function($string);
$serves == 4; //true

$cookingtime = some_kind_of_function($string);
$cookingtime == 10 //true
```

What would be best way of acquiring that?

Thanks!
Adam

Comment: The best way is to use a regular expression.

Comment: So what have you tried ? We're not here to do your work.

Comment: No worries, working on regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this search like this:

```
function findNum ( $str, $search ) {
   if ( preg_match("/" . preg_quote($search, '/') . "\D*\K\d+/i", $str, $m) )
      return $m[0];
   return false;
}

$str = "Serving Time: 5mins
Cooking time 10 mins
Servings 4
Author: Somebody

Directions

1...
2...";

findNum( $str, "Cooking" ); // 10
findNum( $str, "Servings" ); // 4
```

Comment: Thanks @anubhava for pro answer, I think that's the simplest answer. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

you can convert it to an `array` by replacing `space` between the words by `,(comma)`
by using this function

```
$array = explode(' ', $string);
```

now

```
$count = count($array);
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
{
  if($array[$i]=='servings')
  {
    $serves = $array[$i+1]
  }
  if($array[$i]=='time')
  {
    $cookingtime= $array[$i+1]
  }
}

echo $serves;
echo $cookingtime." Minutes";
```

please let me know if you have any issue.